# Select drive for user folder

Tags: windows-10, installation, appdata

Is there a way for selecting a different drive for the user folder when installing windows 10 ? I don't want it to be in c:\ because appdata grows too big after some time and my primary drive is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't, but you can edit your Documents, Videos, Images... after install. I usually do this to separate my files in different disks.

Just right-click on the folder you want to re-locate, click on properties and you'll see a 'location' tab on the window that pops up.

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: The question asks about relocating the Users folder and specifically mentions AppData as the subfolder that needs to be relocated. There is no Location tab in the properties window for either of those folders.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will doing that, seems to be possible to move the folders inside AppData with the same procedure, but I get errors of the "file name is too long...", thanks anyway